# Winscp - не могу редактировать файлы

Tags: сервер, ide, ftp, winscp

Когда нажимаю править, открывается моя IDE, дальше моментально имя файла в IDE меняется на : `index.js(deleted from disk)`. Соответственно, никакого редактирования и перезаливки на сервер не происходит.

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Может кому-то поможет. Решил почитсить папку `C:\Users\{{USER_NAME}}\AppData\Local\Temp`. Все заработало